# How do I switch to another form from a button?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Sorry I'm a mega noob! I have a button on one form, 'GT_entry.vb' - I want to make this button open another form, 'GT_Add_entry' when it is clicked. The button, 'Add another Competitor' is referred to in the design as 'Addgroup'
This is my current code for the button, I did edit it from when i first asked the question but here it is:

```
Private Sub Addgroup_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Addgroup.Click
    GT_Add_entry.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm I did add the  GT_Add_entry.Show()  text underneath a private sub on the GT_entry code page but its telling me that 'show' is not a member of the form. I think I might be doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post the code directly and not as images. Please [edit] your post accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: ^Okay I've edited the post I hope its more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the click event (Addgroup_click(byval sender....)) all you have to do is:

```
    GT_Add_entry.Show()
```

Comment: are you sure the name of the form you want to show is GT_Add_entry?
sure that GT_Add_entry is a form and not any other control?

Comment: Yeah, weirdly enough it works in theory and the coding window doesn't display anything as being wrong, but when it actually comes to running the code the buttons just won't work. I'll take another stab at it later and see if I can fix it